# Question on Hilbert Manifolds

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

I have a very basic question on Hilbert manifolds.

Consider the Hilbert space 
$$
\mathcal{H}:= L^2(S^1)
$$
with $S^1$ the unit circle. 
On $\mathcal{H}$ let us introduce the equivalence relation 
$$
f\sim g : \Leftrightarrow f(\cdot ) = g(\cdot + \alpha)\quad
\mbox{for some  }\alpha \in S^1.
$$
Now define the factor space 
$$
\overline{\mathcal{H}}:= \mathcal{H}/\sim.
$$
What is the structure of $\overline{\mathcal{H}}$? Is it a Hilbert manifold? If so, how to construct the smooth structure? 
I am particularly interested in computing a (Riemannian) distance between two elements of $\overline{\mathcal{H}}$.

Comment: Sorry, I has an answer that was wrong, using Fourier transform. If it can be corrected, I will repost.

Comment: I would be equally interested in the answer for $L^2(G)/G$ if $G$ is a (compact) topological group.

Comment: See Andrew Stacy's answer to the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10200/important-results-that-use-infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Comment: Not a Hilbert manifold.  As the answer(s) have pointed out, you get problems at fixed points of the circle action (indeed, at any point where the circle action has a non-trivial stabiliser).  There's another problem which is that the circle does not act continuously on the Hilbert space - how much of a problem this is will depend on how you want to fix the first problem (for example, you could go for a stratified space).

Answer (score 3):

It probably is NOT a smooth manifold. I think finding a chart around the point corresponding to constants, namely, the fixed points of the action of the group of rotation, is problematic.More precisely, at a fixed point, there is not a well-defined tangent space.